# Split MonkeyAudio (.ape + .cue + .log) of whole audio CD into MP3 of individual tracks

Tags: audio, conversion, mp3, ripping, ape

I have a whole audio CD ripped to single audio file in MonkeyAudio (`.ape`) format, together with `.cue` and `.log` files (using Exact Audio Copy, from comment in `.cue` file).

How would one split this one large audio file into MP3 files of individual tracks, best if with correct ID3 information from `.cue` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [CUE Splitter](http://www.medieval.it/cuesplitter-pc/menu-id-71.html), works like a charm, Windows only.

Comment: That was the program I used, though `cuesplitter` would also work.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [CUETools,](http://www.cuetools.net/wiki/Main_Page) to do it — load up the `.cue` file or `.ape` file with the other one in the same directory, select tracks for cue style and mp3 output and it'll automate the whole process.

Answer (score 3):

**`shnsplit` on Ubuntu 14.04**

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:flacon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y flacon
shntool split -f *.cue -o flac -t '%n - %p - %t' *.ape
```

`flacon` is a GUI for `shntool`, but it comes with all the codecs it needs... otherwise I got the error:

```
shnsplit: warning: failed to read data from input file using format: [ape]
shnsplit:          + you may not have permission to read file: [example.ape]
shnsplit:          + arguments may be incorrect for decoder: [mac]
shnsplit:          + verify that the decoder is installed and in your PATH
shnsplit:          + this file may be unsupported, truncated or corrupt
shnsplit: error: cannot continue due to error(s) shown above
```

In particular, the `flacon` [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~flacon/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) furnishes the `mac` package (Monkey's Audio Console), on which `flacon` depends, which has the `mac` CLI tool, which seems to be the main missing ingredient.

Comment: Only easy to use open source method. Since windows have bash now, also works like a charm on windows.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you could use [mac](http://supermmx.org/linux/mac) to dump the .ape into .wav, then [bchunk](http://he.fi/bchunk/) to split the big .wav file into tracks using information from the .cue file.

.wav to .mp3 can be done with [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net)/[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org).

I'm pretty sure there must be shellscripts that automate the whole process (including the population of ID3 tags), but finding them is a trivial google task, since now you know a lot of keywords.

As you could see, I assumed Linux, if you want to do it using another operating systems, consider to add the os name as tag, to get more precise answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the script I use (its dependences are in the comments):

```
#!/bin/bash
# ll-cue2mp3-320.bash
# cue and audio file basename must be the same. Usage:
# ll-cue2mp3-320.bash `basename *cue .cue`
# It makes mp3 folder in the dir containing rip, put splits
# there in the format 'trackNumber - trackTitle', and convert splits
# to mp3s. Tags are not transfered to the newly born mp3s.
#
# You can specify the this format with a second arg. Default value
# is '%n - %t'. Other options (them are lltag options):
#
# %a means ARTIST 
# %t means TITLE 
# %A means ALBUM 
# %n means NUMBER 
# %g means GENRE 
# %d means DATE 
# %c means COMMENT 
# %i means that the text has to be ignored 
# %F means the original basename of the file 
# %E means the original extension of the file 
# %P means the original path of the file 
#
# Dependences: lltag, lame, cuetools, shntool, flac, wavpack,
# parallel, ape support (if you're going to split ape files)

# Don't forget to put input args in quotes, e.g:
# ll-cue2mp3-320 "name of the cue file" "%a - %t"
#
# TODO:
# convert tags to utf-8 - if they are not


# parsing 1st arg:
fl="$1"
if [ -e "$fl".flac ]; then
    ex="flac"
elif [ -e "$fl".ape ]; then
    ex="ape"
else [ -e "$fl".wv ]
    ex="wv"
fi


# parsing 2nd arg:
frmt="$2"
frmt=${2:-"%n - %t"}


# splitting the dump:
mkdir mp3

cuebreakpoints "$fl".cue | shnsplit -o flac -d mp3 -a split "$fl".$ex && \
    cuetag "$fl".cue mp3/split*\.flac 

cd mp3


# renaming splits basing on tags:
for i in `ls`; do
    lltag --yes --no-tagging --rename "$frmt" $i
done


# converting splits to mp3:
parallel -j+0 flac -d {} ::: *\.flac
parallel -j+0 lame --cbr -b 320 -q 0 {} ::: *\.wav

find . -name "*.flac" | parallel -j+0 rm
find . -name "*.wav" | parallel -j+0 rm

rename 's/\.wav//' *


# done!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ape Ripper to extract audio tracks from Ape image with cue file, Ape Ripper can also convert audio tracks to MP3 files with ID3 tags.

Product URL: http://www.softrm.com/ape-ripper.htm

Ape Ripper is a shareware, you can process 3 Ape images with trial version.

Comment: The OP is asking about splitting the .CUE file

Answer (score 0):

I use  iDealshare VideoGo to split cue based ape, flac, mp3, wav, wma etc

It has both Mac and Windows version.

I like its batch downloading feature.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another free tiny audio converter for WAV MP3 FLAC OGG and APE:
[FlicFlac](http://sector-seven.net/software/flicflac)

[image: screen shot]